# How to find total number of siblings using Jsoup

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsoup

I need to find the total number of siblings in label class and if sibling exists have to append as string..please guide me..

```
<div class="label">About Us: </div>
Hayley’s is one of 
<a rel="tag" title="Sri Lanka Manufacturers" href="http://www.gmdu.net/tags-Sri-Lanka-p1.html">Sri Lanka</a>
’s largest multinational business conglomerates with a history spanning 135 years. Commencing commercial operations in 1878 as Chas. P. Hayley and Company incorporated as Hayley’s Limited 61 years ago. We drive a globally competitive business portfolio encompassing 12 defined sectors of enterprise cutting across manufacturing, Industrial solutions, agriculture and services etc. www.Hayleys.com
<br/>
Haycolour (Pvt) Ltd is one of the largest manufactures for 
<a rel="tag" title="Pigment Emulsion Manufacturers" href="http://www.gmdu.net/tags-Pigment-Emulsion-p1.html">Pigment Emulsion</a>
 in Textile printing Industry in Sri Lanka, Garment panel printing, Latex, Inks and water base paints. We supply to local Textile Printing industry and also export to Asian region, such as Bangladesh, Thailand, Malaysia, Philippines and Pakistan and are open to the rest of the world’s market. Haycolour (Pvt) Limited is a fully owned subsidiary of Hayley’s PLC, Sri Lankas premier blue chip conglomerate. www.haycolour.com , (Site under construction)
<br/>
Haycolour Products are certified by prestigious Hohenstein Institute of Germany for Eco Passport, and Haycolour is proud to be the first 
<a rel="tag" title="Sri Lanka Manufacturers" href="http://www.gmdu.net/tags-Sri-Lanka-p1.html">Sri Lanka</a>
n company to be certified and this proves the stint quality assurance procedures that we have instituted to make our offerings internationally competitive. As an advantage derived through this certification, any Sri-Lankan Supplier/our customer who applies for Okeo Tex 100 certification can use our products and there is no need to test our pigments for Okeo Tex compliances. Eco Passport is worldwide certification on the chemical compliance of production of human ecological optimized textiles. Our product are compliances with free of APEO, AZO, Formaldehyde, Phthalates, heavy metals etc.  And our pigment emulsions are certified to use on baby Garments which is another significant factor.
<br/>
As a South Asian country manufacturing Pigment Emulsions to be used in Textile and garments exports to EU and America, Haycolour has so many barriers to overcome against the multinational chemical manufactures and competitors in India, Taiwan, Korea and China. But the strategies implemented by the company have helped to capture and remain in Export markets.
<br/>
Our main strength is consistency in quality. We never compromise our quality. This is well accepted by our buyers. Also prompt deliveries and competitive prices are two another major factors which help Haycolour to be strong.
<br/>
Haycolour provides entire solutions to the textile printers in Sri-Lanka and abroad, who cater to the export garment industry. The service includes all the products required for T-shirt printing industry with different types of rubber pastes for cotton, cotton blends and Nylon fabrics, Gillter, Flocks Discharge paste, Crack Binders, Foils, 3D AND SPECIALEFFECTCHEMICALS. Haycolour also provides total solutions to Textile and Garment dyeing industry by representing leading giants in Reactive, Disperse and Nylon dyes in the world market.
<br/>
Thanking you and awaiting your favorable response to start a good and long lasting business relationship with you.
<br/>
</div>
```

Expected Result:
I need to find total number of String and have to append all siblings to String

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#siblingElements%28%29) - this will give you `sibling Elements` for a given `Element`